# MEQP1 standard INSERT detected outside of Resource Model

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, coding-standards

Below line causing warning in **codesniffer** in  **MEQP1** standard

```
$data = $installer->getConnection()->insert($eavTypeTable, array('entity_type_code'=>'test'));
```

This line causing the Warning

> Data access method INSERT detected outside of Resource Model

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is recommended to avoid using **CRUD methods directly** on the **database**. **In M1, CRUD methods should sit in resource models not elsewhere (models, controllers, helpers etc...)**

In your case you can do:

```
$eavType = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_type');
$eavType->setEntityTypeCode('test');
$eavType->save();
```

<del>Side note: I'm pretty this code or your code would fail because the entity type table requires more information than this to insert an entry.</del>

Comment: on a Side note: this code is working.. thanks i will test and back to you.